# Sweetalert2 Swal.mixin - is it possible to extract input data to json / php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, sweetalert2

```
Using this code:
Swal.mixin({
  input: 'text',
  confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
  showCancelButton: true,
  progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
}).queue([
  {
    title: 'Question 1',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy'
  },
  'Question 2',
  'Question 3'
]).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    const answers = JSON.stringify(result.value)
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'All done!',
      html: `
        Your answers:
        <pre><code>${answers}</code></pre>
      `,
      confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
    })
  }
})
```

In this case, my answers:

```
["1","1","2"]
```

how could it receive the values ​​passed in a php file?
I do not know well about both subjects, but I am experiencing this need.
Sorry, and sorry for my english.

Comment: if i understand correctly you have data in `php` file and you want to fetch it in your js code so you need to use `ajax` search for it

Comment: @Joseph In fact, I wanted to pass this data from that code up to PHP.
I just didn't quite understand how to do this. Can you guide me?
I search for this, and found this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847738/sweet-alerts-queue-form?rq=1
Only without any resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Using this code: [Sweet Alerts - Queue form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847738/sweet-alerts-queue-form?rq=1)
Make change swal for Swal.fire

```
  var strAns1;
    var strAns2;

    swal.mixin({
      input: 'text',
      confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
      showCancelButton: true,
      progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
    }).queue([
      {
        title: 'Question 1',
        text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
        preConfirm: function(value)
                {
                    strAns1= value;
                }
      },

      {
        title: 'Question 2',
        text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy',
        preConfirm: function(value)
                {
                    strAns2= value;
                }
      }
    ]).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'All done!',
          html:
            'Your answers: <pre>' +
              JSON.stringify(result) +
            '<pre>Answer1- ' + strAns1+
            '<pre>Answer2- ' + strAns2+
            '</pre>',
          confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
        })
      }
    })
```

Change

```
swal({
      title: 'All done!',
      html:
        'Your answers: <pre>' +
          JSON.stringify(result) +
        '<pre>Answer1- ' + strAns1+
        '<pre>Answer2- ' + strAns2+
        '</pre>',
      confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
    })
  }
})

To

Swal.fire({
      title: 'All done!',
      html:
        'Your answers: <pre>' +
          JSON.stringify(result) +
        '<pre>Answer1- ' + strAns1+
        '<pre>Answer2- ' + strAns2+
        '</pre>',
      confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
    })
  }
})
```

Im get in result this:

```
{"value":["adf","fffff"]}
Answer1- adf
Answer2- fffff
```

Now can I pass this on to a php?
Like for example?
Thank you thank you very much.